# function for removing nonsignificant variables at one step in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to automate logistic regression in R. 
Basically, my source code will generate a new equation everyday as the input data is updated, 
(Variables, data format etc are same) and print out te significant variables with corresponding coefficients. 
When I use step function, sometimes the resulting coefficients are not significant. Therefore, I want to update my set of coefficients and get rid of all the ones that are not significant enough. 
Is there a function or automated way of doing it? 
If not, the only way I can think of is writing a script on another language that takes the coefficients and corresponding P value and checking significance, and rerunning R accordingly. But even for that, do you know how can I get only P values and coefficients of variables. I can either print whole summary of regression result with "summary" function. I can't reach only P values.

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm sure people will give you good technical advice on how to do what you ask, but my advice would be to **seriously reconsider doing this at all**.  There are a (very) few good reasons to do stepwise regression, and many many good reasons not to: see e.g. http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/stat/stepwise.html for a start ...

Comment: and if you insist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701170/stepwise-regression-using-p-value

Comment: Yes, perhaps instead of automating extraction of P-values consider automating extraction of likelihoods and number of parameters.  K. Burnham and D. Anderson have published a bunch of papers and books on model selection and AIC.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the link. In order to automate, stepwise function was the first thing came to my mind. MarkMiller, thanks for the references. I'll read them before my applications

Comment: It would be useful to know *why* you are constructing these logistic regressions -- for prediction (in which case you might want to use multi-model averaging á la Burnham and Anderson, or perhaps better by penalized regression as in the `glmnet` package)? For hypothesis testing? For categorization?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard for me without sample code and data, but you can subset based on variable values like this,

```
newdata <- data[ which(data$p.value < 0.5), ]
```

You can inspect your R object using `str`, see `?str` to figure out how to select whatever you want to use in your subset `$p.value` or `$residuals`.

If this doesn't answer your question try submitting some sample code and data.

Best,
Eric

Comment: Thanks, This might work. I will try it on Monday and let you know.