# how to randomly exchange a column within a function?

Tags: r

I have a matrix and a vector

```
set.seed(1) # I added this to have a reproducible values
X <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=20)
Y <- matrix(rexp(10, rate=.1), ncol=1)
```

Then I randomly select 5 of the columns of X
As @Laterow suggested 
    # select 5 random columns from X
    temp <- sample(ncol(X), 5)
    X1 <- X[,temp]

Then I merge the **X1** with my **Y**

```
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Y,X1))
```

Then I build a regression

```
fit = lm(Y~.,data=mydata)
```

Then i obtain the sd

```
se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))
```

Now what I want to do is to change the column with the largest **se** with all other columns of my original **X** and keep the one with lowest **se**

for example if you run above, in the se, I have the X3 with biggest value

```
          X3  
7.348126e-18
```

so I change the column 3 of X1 with all other columns except itself from the X

Now I want to automatically change column 3 with all other columns except itself from the X

if you do

```
> temp
#[1] 18  4  9  8 10
```

it the X1 column 3 changed by all columns of X except 9

Comment: So... Why don't you just store the information, e.g. `temp <- sample(ncol(X), 5)`, so that you can later check which columns they were? (edit: and then obviously change the code to `X[,temp]`)

Comment: @Laterow Thanks I edited my question now

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to understand what you want to achive

1. "except 9" can't include 1 column twice into lm (without transormation) -collinearity. So you need to change X3 on all columns except already used.

But maybe that :

```
temp <- c(18 , 4 , 9,  8, 10) # your sample 
X1 <- X[,temp] 
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Y,X1))
fit = lm(Y~.,data=mydata)
worst_se=which.max(summary(fit)$coefficients[-1,2]) # find max se without interceprt

Xm=X[,-temp] # all not used X

res2=lapply(1:ncol(Xm),function(i){
  mydata[[worst_se]] <- Xm[ , i]
  summary(lm(Y~.,data=mydata))$coefficients[names(worst_se),"Std. Error"] # return se of changed X3
})
```

You may be have to see about `?step` which used to achive "best" model
or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701170/stepwise-regression-using-p-values-to-drop-variables-with-nonsignificant-p-value) ( you task very similar with it)

## PS

Highest **se** not means worst coef. ( there is some test to check significants of coef in statistics)

Comment: would it be possible to do it automatically from the beginning?   before the temp is calculated ? also  which type of test when you say "there is some test to check significants of coef in statistics"

Comment: Are you read about `step` and what it do? `t-test` for example can be used to check significants. (`p-value` show significants of coef). you need to told by words what you wnat to achive ( find best model with 5 coef from matrix?( what about collinearity and others stats issuse?))

Comment: I want to find which variable among those 5 are less important then i change it with X one by one and keep a better one instead

Comment: at this stage I don't care about collinearity , it is an issue when you check for one independent variable but does not harm the entire model