# how to replace a column of a data frame with several columns alternatively?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
X <- matrix(rexp(30, rate=.1), ncol=5)
Y <- matrix(rexp(6, rate=.1), ncol=1)
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Y,X))
```

Now I want to change the third column of X with each of the columns of Xm

```
Xm <- matrix(rexp(60, rate=.1), ncol=10)
```

and do a linear regression and save the sd of X3. If I want to do it manually I do

```
X[ , 3] <- Xm[ , 1]
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Y,X))
fit1 = lm(Y~.,data=mydata)
```

then

```
X[ , 3] <- Xm[ , 2]
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Y,X))
fit2 = lm(Y~.,data=mydata)
```

then

```
X[ , 3] <- Xm[ , 3]
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Y,X))
fit3 = lm(Y~.,data=mydata)

.
.
.

etc.
```

however, if I do it manually it takes so long and not efficient. Is there anyone who can help me to make it more automatic?

Comment: I think it would be good to edit the question to make clear that you only want the standard errors of the coefficient for X3.

Comment: @Johannes Ranke thanks for your comment, I did it

Comment: Maybe also show how to calculate the sd for X3 in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in loop

like

```
res=lapply(1:ncol(Xm),function(i){
mydata[[3]] <- Xm[ , i] # change 3-rd column of mydata om i-th colomn of Xm
lm(Y~.,data=mydata)
})
```

where `res` - list of your lm models

If you want to save only X3 std 
you can do it in such way

```
res2=lapply(1:ncol(Xm),function(i){
mydata[[3]] <- Xm[ , i]
summary(lm(Y~.,data=mydata))$coefficients["X3","Std. Error"]
})
```

but in your example they all `NaN`

Comment: thanks for your comment, would it be possible to only keep the Std. Error of the X3 for all loops as output ? if so, I accept your answer

Comment: Added , but in question is nothing about it

Comment: please look at this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129153/how-to-randomly-exchange-a-column-within-a-function

Answer (score 1):

maybe with sapply?

```
X <- matrix(rexp(30, rate=.1), ncol=5)
Y <- matrix(rexp(6, rate=.1), ncol=1)
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Y,X))

Xm <- matrix(rexp(60, rate=.1), ncol=10)

sapply(1:ncol(Xm), function(mycol) {
  X[ , 3] <- Xm[ , mycol]
  mydata <- data.frame(cbind(Y,X))
  fit = lm(Y~.,data=mydata) 
  return(sqrt(diag(vcov(fit))))
}, USE.NAMES = F)
```

UPDATE 1:
Modified to extract the standard errors, according to 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17571/how-to-store-the-standard-errors-with-the-lm-function-in-r

Comment: thanks, can you please modify your answer to keep only the Std. Error of X3 for all loop ? please look at summary(fit1)

Comment: modified, please let me know if it's what you intended.

Comment: hmmm... may be `sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))`? because this give error to me `no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')" `

Comment: @Leonardo Foderaro I liked your answer

Answer (score 1):

I like the plyr package, and you wanted the coefficients:

```
myfun = function(x) {
    mydata[[3]] <- x
    coef(lm(Y ~ ., data = mydata))
}

ldply(as.data.frame(Xm), myfun)
```

Comment: look at this question, if you give any solution, I will accept it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129153/how-to-randomly-exchange-a-column-within-a-function